# Sending email to multiple address

Tags: vb.net, email

I want to send email to multiple address, and I created a function for it.

This is my function:

```
Public Function sendMail(IDnums As String, emailAdd As String)
    con.Open()
    Dim adapt As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dtable As DataTable
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

    adapt = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblRequestPasscode", con)
    dtable = New DataTable
    adapt.Fill(dtable)
    Try
        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("asukaliboguidanceoffice@gmail.com", "S1F6u1d@nc3Syst3m")
        Smtp_Server.Port = 587
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        e_mail = New MailMessage()
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress("asukaliboguidanceoffice@gmail.com")

        e_mail.To.Add(emailAdd)   <<---------------------<<<<

        e_mail.Subject = "Requested Passcode"
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
        e_mail.Body = "Your requested passcode is " + final.ToString + ". Use this along with your ID Number to fully access ASU-CIT Guidance System."
        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
        cutConn()
    Catch error_t As Exception
        MsgBox("Connection error. Please check you internet connection then try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Connection Error!")
        cutConn()
    End Try
    con.Open()
    Try
        cmd = New MySqlCommand
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "UPDATE tblRequestPasscode SET Status ='0', Passcode ='" & final.ToString & "' WHERE IDNo ='" & IDnums.ToString & "'"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in updating passcode.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "")
        cutConn()
    End Try
    final = String.Empty
    cutConn()

    Return IDnums = "" And emailAdd = ""

End Function
```

I'm getting an error on the line:  e_mail.To.Add(emailAdd)

"The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

It's working if it is like this: e_mail.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com")

How to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you calling sendMail? Is the string being passed in?

Comment: Yes sir, I'm passing it.

Comment: sendMail(noOfid, emailAddress)

Comment: Couldnt you just pass in a , seperated string of email addresses? IE someone@gmail.com, Someoneelse@gmail.com

Comment: Are you sure the content of emailAdd is an email address?

Comment: It's from my database with varchar datatype on my xampp DB

Comment: And you debugged it to verify it is a valid email address with no other funkiness going on? Simple logging statements could verify this.

Comment: I got it! I display the value to a messagebox and notice that I'm fetching passcode rather than email address. What the heck! Well, thanks again sir.

Comment: I made it like this, e_mail.To.Add(CType(emailAdd, String))

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the vb forums: [Sending Multiple emails](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?603480-sending-email-to-multiple-addresses)

you can add multiple e-mail addresses that way as long as they are comma separated.

Comment: Url goes no where when clicked.

Comment: Sorry! Check it now!

Comment: From his code he's sending each individual a different passcode, so comma separated isn't viable.

Comment: Did the link provide you with the answer to your question?

Comment: I found a way to check the value if it is really an email add. But I mess up and I fixed it, thanks for the help sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with VBA using the concept below.

Make a list in Sheets("Sheet1") with :

In column A : Names of the people
In column B : E-mail addresses
In column C:Z : Filenames like this C:\Data\Book2.xls (don't have to be Excel files)

The Macro will loop through each row in "Sheet1" and if there is a E-mail address in column B
and file name(s) in column C:Z it will create a mail with this information and send it.

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Testfile"
                .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```